# Scrupulous obsessive compulsion disorder

Tags: vedanta

Pls explain the Hindu system of sin for people who are suffering from scrupulous ocd , which makes a person have intrusive thoughts which are largely negative towards God he so dearly loves , because if it's sin it's done by it's mind , not him , if it's his why will he feel negative about it , pls provide an answer ;

Comment: This is not the right place to ask for answers for *psychiatry*.  OCD and problems regarding *religious melancholy* should be treated first at professional medical care. Religion, like all areas of study, accepts skepticism and different point of views of all order. A spiritually healthy growth is impossible without such.

Answer (score 0):

Your question must be still more explanatory.
"if it's sin it's done by it's mind , not him" - the statement you cited

Answer: Dont give such persons food for 3 days, then is it not his mind that grabs food fourth day as soon as food given or
Still u want to get confused by your statement "its mind not him"

Answer (score 0):

Since thoughts are largely governed by the Grahas and Rashis. Your horoscope will show this. As for what sins you committed to get in this situation, that will be shown by the D-30 chart for sins/evils and D-60 chart for past life karma. It will also show effect in the D-6 Chart for diseases/illnesses in relation to Moon, Saturn and Mars. Possibly the 9th or 12 house will be involved in this in the D-30 with Saturn's or Rahu's involvement with Moon.

You should consult a Jyotishi who is well versed in the Shashtras with your accurate time and location of birth if your goal is to know the reason.